# Is threading the best way to handle 40 Clients at a time in UDP Server?

Tags: c, winapi, network-programming, udp

I am working on a UDP server/client application.

I want my server to be able to handle 40 clients at a time. I have thought of creating 40 threads at server side, each thread handling one client. Clients are distinguished on the basis of IP addresses and there is one thread for each unique IP address.

Whenever a client sends some data to a server, the main thread extracts the IP address of the client and decides which thread will process this specific client. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, using threads is certainly one way. How much traffic is there per client? How much work would each thread do? If it's just little traffic with simple work, then using only the main thread might be enough. If not try a smaller set of threads, each thread handling multiple clients.

Comment: My suggestion is actually to start doing it in the one single "main" thread. If you notice that the server can't keep up, then split into two threads, one doing the communication and one doing the work. If it still doesn't work good enough, then two threads, each handling half of the clients. And so on until you're happy with the performance.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Thank you so much for your response, but I am a little confused that how can I use same Socket of Server in 40 different Threads. e.g. two Threads two of the Threads simultaneously try to send data, but since there is only one bind()ed socket, how will this send()ing be done from two threads simultaneously?

Comment: With UDP you don't use `send` to send to a client, you use `sendto` instead. The network stack will be able to handle it. You just have to be careful to not have multiple threads call `sendto` at the same time, either by having a single thread do all the communication or by protecting the sending with a mutex or similar.

Comment: So if I have 40 threads, I shall have to handle sendto() using Mutex in all of the 40 threads? :(

Comment: That's why you should start with a smaller amount of threads, preferably no extra threads at all, and work your way up from there.

Comment: Is there a specific operating system are you targeting? Many OSes provide different flavors of non-blocking IO functionality which allows to implement multi-user servers without explicit multithreading.

Comment: I am working on windows 7 right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches for scale able server application, one thread per client seems good if no of clients are not many, another most efficient approach to accomplish this task is to use thread pool. These threads are work as task base when ever you have any new task assign this task to free worker thread.

Comment: winapi seems to have support for thread pools built in.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this project, I think it is very helpful to start with: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16935/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-UDP-sockets

> With IPAddress.Any, we specify that the server should accept client
>   requests coming on any interface. To use any particular interface, we
>   can use IPAddress.Parse (“192.168.1.1”) instead of IPAddress.Any. The
>   Bind function then bounds the serverSocket to this IP address. The
>   epSender identifies the clients from where the data is coming.
>
> With BeginReceiveFrom, we start receiving the data that will be sent
>   by the client. Note that we pass epSender as the last parameter of
>   BeginReceiveFrom, the AsyncCallback OnReceive gets this object via the
>   AsyncState property of IAsyncResult, and it then processes the client
>   requests (login, logout, and send message to the users). Please see
>   the code attached to understand the implementation of OnReceive.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the [Proactor pattern](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) (take a look at [Boost.Asio library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)), instead of creating thread per client. With such an approach your application would have much better scalability and performace (especially on platforms that have native async i/o)

Besides, with this technique the threading would be de-coupled from the concurrency, meaning that you don't necessarily have to mess with multi-threading with all its complications.